# replace a list of values by another in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with any of these values.

```
from=c("A","C","G","T","R","Y","M","K","W", "S","N")
```

and I want to replace accordingly with

```
to=c("AA","CC","GG","TT","AG","CT","AC","GT","AT", "CG","NN")
```

What is the best way to do that , loop over all values to replace? or loop over matrix position. or any other solution?

```
dd<-matrix(sample(from, 100, replace=TRUE), 10) 

dd
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,] "K"  "S"  "G"  "T"  "R"  "N"  "A"  "C"  "W"  "M"  
 [2,] "Y"  "K"  "S"  "G"  "T"  "R"  "N"  "A"  "C"  "W"  
 [3,] "M"  "Y"  "K"  "S"  "G"  "T"  "R"  "N"  "A"  "C"  
 [4,] "W"  "M"  "Y"  "K"  "S"  "G"  "T"  "R"  "N"  "A"  
 [5,] "C"  "W"  "M"  "Y"  "K"  "S"  "G"  "T"  "R"  "N"  
 [6,] "A"  "C"  "W"  "M"  "Y"  "K"  "S"  "G"  "T"  "R"  
 [7,] "N"  "A"  "C"  "W"  "M"  "Y"  "K"  "S"  "G"  "T"  
 [8,] "R"  "N"  "A"  "C"  "W"  "M"  "Y"  "K"  "S"  "G"  
 [9,] "T"  "R"  "N"  "A"  "C"  "W"  "M"  "Y"  "K"  "S"  
[10,] "G"  "T"  "R"  "N"  "A"  "C"  "W"  "M"  "Y"  "K"
```

I used loop over all from to to.

```
myfunc<-function(xx){

  from=c("A","C","G","T","R","Y","M","K","W", "S","N");
  to=c("AA","CC","GG","TT","AG","CT","AC","GT","AT", "CG","NN");
  for (i in 1:11){
      xx[xx==from[i]]<-to[i];
  }
  return(xx);
}
```

it worked great for small matrix, but takes a long time for big matrix. Any effcient solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Create a map

```
map = setNames(to, from)
```

and go from A to B

```
dd[] = map[dd]
```

The map serves as a look-up, associating 'from' names with 'to' values. The assignment preserves matrix dimensions and dimnames.

Comment: Thank, but I got an error   `>> map = setNames(to, from)
> ll2[]<-map[ll]
Error in map[ll] : invalid subscript type 'list'`

Comment: @Ananta I guess `ll` is a data.frame, not matrix, so different from your question. You could `ll[] = map[as.matrix(ll)]`. Also not clear what `ll2` is; maybe you want to re-visit your question? Be careful, as data frame columns could well be factors.

Comment: @Martin, Yes it worked ll was indeed dataframe. ll2 was created just to preserve ll in case something goes wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
matrix(to[match(dd,from)], nrow=nrow(dd))
```

`match` returns a vector without dimensions, so you need to recreate the matrix.

Answer (score 3):

I used a similar for loop as OP and timed the solutions. Theodore's one is fastest by a slight margin, but Martin's is very readable.

```
dd<-matrix(sample(from, 100, replace = TRUE),10,10)
ddr <- dd
ddm <- dd
ddt <- dd

benchmark(roman = {
  for (i in 1:length(from)) {
    ddr[ddr == from[i]] <- to[i]
  }},
  martin = {
    map = setNames(to, from)
    ddm[] = map[dd]
  },
theodore = {ddt <- matrix(to[match(dd,from)], nrow=nrow(dd))},
          replications = 100000
)
      test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2   martin       100000    1.93    1.191      1.91        0         NA        NA
1    roman       100000    8.23    5.080      8.11        0         NA        NA
3 theodore       100000    1.62    1.000      1.61        0         NA        NA
```