# R ifelse is erroneously replacing text with integers

Tags: r

I have some data that I'm working with from a Udacity course (Link: [Reddit Survey Responses](https://s3.amazonaws.com/udacity-hosted-downloads/ud651/reddit.csv)). I'm trying to simplify the Employment Status variable by replacing any multi-word values with single word alternates using

```
RS$employment.status <- ifelse(RS$employment.status == "Not employed,  but looking for work",
                               "Unemployed", RS$employment.status)
```

However, when I run the code any values that **aren't supposed to be replaced** are replaced with numeric values. Given that the else case is to use the field's value, I'm not sure why the text isn't preserved as-is.

Here's a screenshot of the initial data
[image]

And the after
[image]

So if anyone could point out

1. why the substitution is being made when it doesn't look like it should be;
2. what would be the correct way to accomplish what I'm trying to achieve;

it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please read [about how to provide a minimum, working, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: what is the type of the column? You are replacing your data with a character type but you may have a factor as your current column type

Comment: I couldn't easily find a duplicate for this problem, which is one that might be tricky for beginners to diagnose.  This question will likely be of use to future searchers, though it would be better with a minimum example of your data, code, & results.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912210/replace-a-list-of-values-by-another-in-r/15912309#15912309) is a different approach to a number of `ifelse()` statements; you'll want to make sure you coerce the original column to character() before doing the map.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that this variable is set as a Factor, so to fix your problem you can either add this argument when you read your data **stringsAsFactors = FALSE** or you could do this:

```
  RS$employment.status <- ifelse(RS$employment.status == "Not employed, but looking for work", 
"Unemployed", as.character(RS$employment.status))
```

Comment: Thanks! After Michal's comment I checked and they are being imported as factors. For future reference is there a way to force R to default to NEVER using factors (for strings, ints, floats/doubles, etc.)?

Comment: @JMichael you can add options("stringsAsFactors"=FALSE) at the beginning of you code every time, I don't know if there is a way to do it for every R session

Comment: @JMichael Yes, you can put that in your .Rprofile. However, be aware that writing code under those circumstances will make it very dangerous to share your code with others. There will likely be strange bugs because they haven't set that option and it will be very difficult to diagnose.

Comment: Another option is to read in your data using functions from the [`readr` package](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/04/09/readr-0-1-0/), which by default do not convert to strings to factors (and, as a bonus, `readr` is much faster than base functions for reading data).

Comment: @eipi10 Thanks! Figured there was something like that out there. Just hadn't gotten that far yet. I'll be installing that now.